# JQuery Autocomplete without polluting global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

So I have got a working solution for Jquery Autocomplete, but my Solution does pollute the global namespace. I tried to encapsule it within an object, but sadly functions withing the object are not be able to accessed.

Here my example:

```js
var Source = [ 'Foo', 'Bar' , 'Baz'];

    function Focused() {
        console.log("Focused");
    };
    function Selected() {
        console.log("Selected");
    };
    var autcompleteOptions = {
        minLength: 1,
        source: Source,
        select: Selected,
        focus: Focused,
        position: {  collision: "flip"  }
    };
    function setup() {
        $("#Steelgrade").autocomplete(autcompleteOptions)
            .bind('focus', function () {
                $("#Steelgrade").autocomplete("search");
            });
    }
    setup();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input type="text" id="Steelgrade"/>
```

Edit: If i try to encasule it within an object , the functions with autocomplete are now defined:

```js
var Steelautocomplete = (function(){
     var Source = [ 'Foo', 'Bar' , 'Baz'];
     var Focused =  function() {
            console.log("Focused");
        };
     var Selected = function() {
            console.log("Selected");
        };
     var autcompleteOptions = {
            minLength: 1,
            source: Source,
            select: Selected,
            focus: Focused,
            position: {  collision: "flip"  }
        };
     var setup = function () {
            $("#Steelgrade").autocomplete(autcompleteOptions)
                .bind('focus', function () {
                    $("#Steelgrade").autocomplete("search");
                });
        };
        return{
         Setup:setup
        };
   })();
   Steelautocomplete.Setup();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input type="text" id="Steelgrade"/>
```

Could anybody point out where i did  go wrong with my context ?

Edit: Thanks for pointing out the difference between module and namespace. I changed my second example to working code as namespace variant.

Comment: Are you just trying to assign an alternate Namespace for your code? I am confused about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I use Razorpages with .NET Framework and therefore mostly code is put in partial views with script tags. I want a compent style based approach and in order to not pollute the window object  its neccessary to encapusle the module code.

Comment: *in order to not pollute the window object its necessary to encapsulate the module code* - no, that's not the reason to use modules.  If don't want to pollute window, then use namespaces.  If you want a module, use modules.  Don't mix them up.